# App resets data to zero even though its stored on firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an app that is basically a calculator for users to add up a total amount they have won from certain games. When I input a figure that is not a whole number - "$1.25" for instance, it saves on firebase as "$1.25" but when I close the app and reopen the value gets reset to $0.00 but stays stored as $1.25" on firebase. 
If I do the same thing with a whole number - "$1" for instance, and close the app and open, the "$1" stays on the app.

```
//add local data
        let gameKey = gameNames[addWinningsView.tag]
        let newValue = amountList[addWinningsView.tag] + (Double(addWinningsAmount.text!) ?? 0)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: gameKey)
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

        //Update UI
        loadTotalAmount()

        //update to firebase
         let uuid = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor!.uuidString
        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("app_data/user_total_won/\(uuid)/\(gameKey)")
        ref.setValue(newValue)
```

Code that loads data from firebase

```
//Load winning points
        let uuid = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor!.uuidString
        Database.database().reference().child("app_data/user_total_won/\(uuid)").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in
            let dict = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] ?? [:]

            for game in gameNames {
                let amount = dict[game] as? Int ?? 0
                UserDefaults.standard.set(amount, forKey: game)
                UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
            }
            self.loadTotalAmount()
        }
```

Expected results: Retrieve data from firebase that isn't just a whole number.

Comment: What is your code that queries the database to display the current value?

Comment: I made an edit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are retrieving the value from Firebase, optional cast it `as? Double` not `Int` so you won't just get whole numbers.

To fix the issue, change `let amount = dict[game] as? Int ?? 0` to `let amount = dict[game] as? Double ?? 0` if you are saving the amount as a `Double` in Firestore.